# The coefficient of $x^{6}$ in { $(1+x)^{6}$ + $(1+x)^{7}$ + ... + $(1+x)^{15}$ } is?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

The coefficient of  $x^{6}$ in { $(1+x)^{6}$ + $(1+x)^{7}$  + ... + $(1+x)^{15}$  } is ?

---

Options:

a) **16**C**9**

b) **16**C**5** - **6**C**5**

c) (**16**C**6**) - 1

---

Now I have the answer as:

**6**C**6 + 7**C**6 +  ..... + 15**C**6**

which I got after taking the coefficients from each term.

***I am unable to express this answer in the terms of the options given. How do I do that?***

Comment: take $(1+x)^6$ outside then use gp sum

Comment: @MANMAID That idea didn't struck me at first. So is there any way I can get to the answer using the answer I found? This is because if the idea of finding the sum of the GP didn't struck me now, it may not in the exam too and I may use the same method.

Comment: Have you heard of the [hockey stick identity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity)? Also, the GP sum method gives you what you already have, the sum of 10 binomial coefficients.

Comment: yah! I forgot that identity ... thanks @Arthur

Comment: No @Arthur . Is it taught to a 12th grade student where you live?

Comment: @MANMAID Why do you think that I would feel humiliated by Arthur's comment? I was just curious and hence, asked. Also, despite being a JEE aspirant, I haven't been taught Hockey Stick Identity.

Comment: @SiddharthGarg if JEE applicant then you must go for GP procedure... it is the quickest way, I guess.

Answer (score 12):

Obviously, we have $$(1+x)^{6} + (1+x)^{7}  + \ldots + (1+x)^{15}=\frac{(1+x)^{16}-(1+x)^{6}}x,$$ so we need the coefficient of $x^7$ of the numerator. That can come only from the first term and is $\binom{16}7=\binom{16}9,$ so it's option a).

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

$$(1+x)^6+...+(1+x)^{15}=\frac{(1+x)^6(1-(1+x)^{10})}{1-1-x}$$
$$=\frac{(1+x)^{16}-(1+x)^6}{x}$$

The above is by using geometric series sum.